# How do I invoke an Objective-C `initFoo` method with no arguments from Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have an Objective-C class that declares methods like:

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject

- (instancetype) initWithDefaultsFoo;
- (instancetype) initWithDefaultsBar;

@end
```

XCode automatically generates a corresponding Swift interface:

```
open class MyClass : NSObject {
    public init!(defaultsFoo: ())
    public init!(defaultsBar: ())
}
```

But how do I construct `MyClass` from Swift?

I've tried:

```
var x = MyClass(defaultsFoo: ()) // ERROR: Editor placeholder in source file.
var y = MyClass(defaultsBar: nil) // ERROR: Nil is not compatible with expected argument type '()'
```

Comment: Yikes! That's one nasty translation to convert such Objective-C initializers to Swift. I guess that's the least nasty way to disambiguate differently named, zero-parameter Objective-C initializers.

Comment: I imagine adding a proper "nullable"/"not nullable" specifier to those Objective-C initializer return types will give a Swift `init` without the odd `!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x = MyClass(defaultsFoo: ())
```

should work.  The reason why it seemingly didn't was because when XCode autocompleted the call, it filled in a placeholder that *looks like* `()` but isn't actually `()`.

[image]

(Note the blue highlighting. Inspecting the file on disk also shows that the placeholder is written out as `<#T##()#>`.)

Alternatively:

```
var x = MyClass(defaultsFoo: Void())
```

also seems to work but is probably uglier.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you're encountering is a bug in your Objective-C; no initializer should look like that. Either the initializer should be `init` and take no parameter or it should be `initWith...` and take a parameter. Your Objective-C violates the naming conventions, and Swift's translation of it correspondingly goes up in flames.